# Frequency content of varying hammer tip hits

Tags: energy, frequency

In order to experimentally determining the modes of an object, a modal analysis can be performed. In this experiment, an object is excited by hitting it with a hammer and measuring the response with a sensor. 
For the experiment, the type of hammer tip is important. Soft hammer tips excite lower frequencies of the object with a high amplitude, and stiff tips a larger band of frequencies with a lower content (see figure below, assuming equal energy in both hits).

[image: Frequency content of varying hammer tip hits]

My question is: why do stiff tips excite a larger band of frequencies? Is it because the sharper an impulse peak, the higher the frequency content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right! The sharper the impulse peak in time, the broader the frequency band generated. This follows from the Fourier decomposition of the impulse amplitude $A(t)$ $$ A(\omega)=\frac {1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}A(t)exp(-i\omega t) dt$$ In the extreme case of a Dirac delta function impulse $A(t)= \delta(t-t_0)$, you get a constant amplitude $A(\omega)$ in the whole frequency spectrum.